# is it the recursive function being triggered in C#

Tags: c#, loops, recursion

I have called a function inside a function. However, I found the function GetExpression() inside the Calculate() function is run many times. It seems some loop is run or recursive is run. I cannot figure out how it is being run many times, not sure how it is being loop or recursive. I found in application log, that the GetExpression is run many times when the Calculate funtions is run. Am I missing some information to find out how it is being loop? Please help.

```
public DataSet Calculate(int compID, DateTime? fromDate, DateTime? toDate, string indiIDs)
{
    bool allowGetting = true; 
    DataSet results = null; 

    try
    {            
        string unit = null;
        bool isEnabled = IsResultsEnabled(comID);
        if (isCalResultEnabled)
        {
            unit = GetUnit(comID, indicatorIDs, callerAcceptedUnit);
            results = CheckResults(comID, indicatorIDs, unit);
            EnsureUpToDate(comID, results);
            if (calculatedResults.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                allowGetting = false;
            }
        }

        if (!allowGetting && results != null)
        {
            DataSet ds = GenerateResults(results);
            return ds;
        }
        else
        {                    
            string expression = GetExpression(compID, fromDate, toDate, indiIDs);        

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            dt.Columns.Add("Expression");
            dt.Columns.Add("Result", Type.GetType("System.Decimal"));
            DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();
            newRow["Expression"] = expression;

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(expression))
            {
                newRow["Result"] = DBNull.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                if (expression.EndsWith("+"))
                {
                    expression = expression.Substring(0, expression.Length - 1);
                }

                object result = null;
                try
                {                            
                    result = dt.Compute(expression, "");
                    newRow["Result"] = Convert.ToDecimal(result);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Logger.Log(string.Format("Error occurs");
                    throw;
                }
            }

            dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
            return ds;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (results != null)
        {
            results.Dispose();
            results = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is being called from somewhere else, there is no recursion unless  `Calculate` is being called from a method like GetExpression

Comment: catch
{
    throw;
} doesn't do anything. It's the same as not catching at all.

Comment: If you comment out the definition of GetExpression and then try to build the app, the compiler will let you know where the method is being called from. If it is only called from within Calculate then you must have something calling Calculate multiple times. Without more code, we can't tell.

Comment: How about using the debugger - put a break point in GetExpression & check the stack trace.

Comment: What does GetExpression() do?